# Vuepress create H1 from .md file title

Tags: javascript, vue.js, markdown, vuepress

In .md file I've got a title name but vuepress just changes the HTML title but I want it to create a `<h1> Just a simple title </h1>`  in the document. Is there a way to do it, maybe create a custom rule for .md file?

```
---
title: Just a sample title
---
```

Comment: shouldn´t it be just: `# Just a sample title` ?

Comment: Yes but I've a hundreds of files with this pattern ---
title: Just a sample title
---  
and want to output the <h1>, because   manually changing it to # Just a sample title will be hell

Comment: hmn well that depends on ur text-editor capabilities and skills, could be a simple find and replace. But i guess theres a better solution i dont know vue

Answer (score 0):

The `frontmatter` property `title` is parsed into the `$page.title` property for the page's Vue component. Use the following VuePress [Templating/Interpolation](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html#interpolation) to access the `$page` object.

```
---
title: "My Page Title"
---

# {{ $page.title }}
```

This will render `<h1>My Page Title</h1>` in the HTML. You would have to paste `# {{ $page.title }}` on every page though.